# Controle de NameSpaces de XML em C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Olá!

Estou construindo um arquivo XML e ele possui o o atributo xmlns no elemento pai, mas não quero que ele apareça no filho como está ocorrendo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código em linguagem C#:

```
eSocialevt1210Lote = new XDocument(
     new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "No"),
     new XElement(eSocial + "eSocial",
     new XElement("envioLoteEventos",
```

Answer (score 0):

Lendo um pouco a documentação encontrei o seguinte:
o atributo xmlns significa [NameSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093(v=vs.110).aspx), e também existe vários exemplos, no seu caso, teste isso:

```
XNamespace nameSpace = "http://www.esocial...";

XElement xmlTree = new XElement(nameSpace + "eSocial",
     new XElement(eSocial + "eSocial",
     new XElement("envioLoteEventos",
);

Console.WriteLine(xmlTree );
```

Não testei, mas acredito que seja isso.